# Raspberry Pi Redirect usb microphone to hdmi audio

Tags: raspberry-pi, io-redirection, microphone, hdmi

I have working HDMI audio and can see the usb microphone but I'm not sure what the ALSA settings are to send live audio out through HDMI. I don't want to record just patch through as I'm using it as a live camera to an hdmi monitor in another room and need real time audio, video. I'm using raspivid to run the camera part.

I've tried arecord -D plughw:1,0 | aplay but there is a long delay of about a one second. I need it to sync up with the video.

Also: jackd -r -d alsa -D -Chw:1 -Phw:0 -r 44100. Server runs but nothing happens, no audio out.

Comment: What did you find so far on the web, first, and how did those suggestions not work for your specific setup?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in doing this, I found an answer that works really well. This is the simplest and lowest latency I've found.

NOTE: This isn't headless. You will need more work to get this to work headless.

What I did to make a HDMI live camera with audio:

```
(Note: I'm assuming that pi is the user. Edit accordingly if not.)

1. Get a raspberry pi camera module and a USB microphone.

2. Get and compile Tinyalsa https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa and
   install according to git hub instructions.

3. (Optional) Force hdmi audio with raspi-config. You may not need this
   but default is auto so if you start your Pi without an HDMI monitor
   it will default to outputting to the 3.5mm jack.

4. copy /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart to 
   ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

5. add these lines to the end of ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart:

   /usr/bin/raspivid -t 0
   /home/pi/runtinycap.sh

   (Note: you can put an @ sign before them if you want to 
   automatically restart if the apps crash, but I haven't tested.)

6. create /home/pi/runtinycap.sh with these lines (need to know the audio card
   numbers and may also need the card device numbers using -d after the -D's):

   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/local/bin/tinycap -- -D <card no> -c 1 -r 44100 -b 16 -p 16 -n 2 | /usr/local/bin/tinyplay - -D <card no> -c 1 -r 44100 -b 16 -p 16 -n 2
```

I hope this helps as this was a very painful exercise that took over 8hrs to figure out as there is very little info just Googling!

The latency is WAY better then Jack, QjackCtl, pulseaudio, arecord piped into aplay etc. I couldn't set the -p to less than 2048 and -n 4 without Jack crashing and there was about 140ms latency. TinyAlsa is only 16 and 2! I don't know the exact latency but it's very low. The video and the audio are in sync.